# How to call a function after While loop condition not met c#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have a function which uses while to loop and keep fetching data if condition is met.

```
public static void RetrieveData()
{
    //if datetime in db is earlier then systemdatetime.now 
    while (CompareDate.CompareDateTime() < 0)
    {
        Common.GetLastTime();
        //while timespan of datetime is more then 10 minutes, so stops 10 minute before system time
        if (CompareDate.CompareTimespan() > 0)
        {
            DownloadData.GetFromApi("devicetypes", 
                                    "7654321234", 
                                    CreateCommand.BCurrentTimetoUnix(), 
                                    CreateCommand.SCurrentTimetoUnix());
        }
        //while timespan of datetime is =10 minutes, 
        else if (CompareDate.CompareTimespan() == 0)
        {
            DownloadData.GetFromApi("devicetypes", 
                                    "7654321234", 
                                    CreateCommand.BCurrentTimetoUnix(), 
                                    CreateCommand.SCurrentTimetoUnix());
        }
    }
    //if condition is not met run this
    DownloadData.GetFromApi("devicetypes", 
                            "7654321234", 
                            CreateCommand.BCurrentTimetoUnix(), 
                            CreateCommand.SCurrentTimetoUnix());
}
```

I want to make it so that if the while condition is not met or on codes:

```
CompareDate.CompareDateTime() >=0
```

run this once and program ends after.

```
   DownloadData.GetFromApi("devicetypes", 
                           "7654321234", 
                           CreateCommand.BCurrentTimetoUnix(), 
                           CreateCommand.SCurrentTimetoUnix());
```

Comment: Your current method would do the required, or you mean to loop repeatedly and when condition met, do what is in the while loop and when condition not met do call the DownloadData method?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: do whats in the while loop when condition for the while is met and when condtition for the while is not met run the line at the bottom @peeyushsingh

Comment: @John i am not sure if it is correct or not thats is why i am asking. Maybe an answer like " yes yours would work" would be better". Anyways thanks for taking time to comment.

Comment: I see. Thank you for clearing that up. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're after, but I feel that adding `return;` after `GetFromApi` in the 2 `if`s may do what you want.

```
if (CompareDate.CompareTimespan() > 0)
{
  DownloadData.GetFromApi(...);
  return; <---- 
}
 if (CompareDate.CompareTimespan() > 0)
{
   DownloadData.GetFromApi(...);
  return; <----
}
```

---

Option 2 as I'm still not sure what you after.

```
if( CompareDate.CompareDateTime() >= 0) 
{
  DownloadData.GetFromApi("devicetypes", "7654321234",...)
}
else 
{
  while (CompareDate.CompareDateTime() < 0)
  {
     ...
  }

  // Nothing here
}
```

Comment: what does the return do ?

Comment: The `return` makes the function "stop". `break` will make `while` "stop".

Comment: ok so what i want it to do is that if the condition in the while() is met it will continue with the if statements either one where the condition is met. IF condition is not met in the while() it will just run the line of code at the bottom .

Comment: In this case your code will already do that or maybe check option 2 in the answer.